# Удалить построчно после символа (Delphi XE4)

Tags: delphi

Как решить вот такую задачу на Delphi XE4 ?

В текстовом файле есть строки, например: `-----++Программа+55`

1. Как удалить все после `+`, чтобы получилось: `-----++Программа+`?
2. Как удалить все включая `+`, чтобы получилось: `-----++Программа`?
3. Как обрезать `-----++` и все после `+`, чтобы получилось: `Программа`?

**UPD**

Пробовала вот так:

```
var s:string; 
begin 
  s :='-----++Программа+'; 
  Delete(s, Pos('+', s)+2, Length(s)); 
  ShowMessage(s); //результат 
end;
```

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, что вы уже попробовали сами и что у вас не получилось.

Comment: Регулярками можно...

Comment: Пробовала вот так: var
s:string;
begin
s :='-----++Программа+';
Delete(s, Pos('+', s)+2, Length(s));
ShowMessage(s); //результат
end;

Comment: Но не получается.

Comment: Вы привели только один вариант строки. Я не вижу всех критериев, по которым необходимо удалять символы. Обязательно искомая строка должна быть между '++' и '+'? Или в строке должны остаться только буквы, но не символы?

Comment: Да. Обязательно искомая строка должна быть между '++' и '+'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Да. Обязательно искомая строка должна быть между '++' и '+'

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  s:string;
  k:integer;

begin
   s:='-----++Программа+55';
   k:=Pos('++',s);
   s:=Copy(s,k+2,Length(s)-k-2);
   k:=Pos('+',s);
   s:=Copy(s,1,k-1);
   Writeln(s);
   Readln;

end.
```

Если же через Delete, то так:

```
   s:='-----++Программа+55';
   k:=Pos('++',s);
   Delete(s,1,k+1);
   k:=Pos('+',s);
   Delete(s,k,Length(s)-k+1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.

Comment: @Татьяна, отметьте, пожалуйста, данный ответ как верный.